# Boot Ubuntu 18.04 from a software raid array?

Tags: boot, raid, mdadm

Is it possible to boot Ubuntu 18.04 from a software raid (containing all our system and data)? We have a [Lenovo P71](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-p/ThinkPad-P71/p/22TP2WPWP71) with a regular hard drive and 2 M.2 SSD modules that all work fine and what we want to do is to configure the M.2's as raid 1 (Ubuntu doesn't find them when using hardware raid, and we haven't found out why!) and then remove the hard drive. The M.2's are blinding fast but if something happens you can't recover anything, therefore raiding them is our insurance policy!

Thanks in advance for any help/advice.

Mel

Comment: When you say Software RAID, do you mean BIOS/FakeRAID or Linux MDADM. Ubuntu Software RAID vs FakeRaid vs Hardware RAID. Home user
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2422516&p=13873154#post13873154 You may have to use Server installer & add desktop of choice. Note that RAID is not backup. If data lost on one drive, mirror will also lose it.

Comment: Not recommended. Replace the HDD with an SSD and boot from it instead.

Comment: I have cloned the hard drive to one of the M.2's (and booted from it) and it is blazing fast, in fact much faster than an SSD drive as the SSD still goes thru the SATA controller and the M.2's do not (much higher data rate). Since I have 2 of the M.2's installed it makes sense to put them into a raid 1 for safety in case one of them dies. If that is not possible then backing up one to the other periodically (clonezilla ?) is the only option?